# Jammit and Grouped Package Includes

Tags: ruby, sinatra, jammit

Got an assets.yml file for my sinatra app that's using Jammit.

Here's an example of what I want to accomplish but cannot.

```
  application: &application
    - app/assets/js/vendor/jquery-2.1.1.js
    - app/assets/js/vendor/underscore.js
    - app/assets/js/underscore.strings.js


  other_app:
    - <<: *application
    - app/assets/js/underscore.strings.js
    - app/assets/js/vendor/angularjs/angular.js
    - app/assets/js/vendor/angularjs/angular-sanitize.js
    - app/assets/js/vendor/angular_plugins/**/*.js
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
no implicit conversion of Hash into String
```

It's easy enough to include other packages in my layouts, but that means more and more requests and I can't as easily imply a required assets order. (e.g. this package needs angular include before).

A solid half day of Googling led to nothing! 
Thank SO!

Comment: I believe its indentation problem only, nothing else. you can validate your .yml content at http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/ .And trying it, clearly shows that it is not able to parse it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess its indentation problem only, nothing else. You can validate your .yml content at

```
http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/
```

And trying it, clearly shows that it is not able to parse it correctly. Copy the below content exactly same way, and it will start parsing correctly:

```
 application: &application
  - app/assets/js/vendor/jquery-2.1.1.js
  - app/assets/js/vendor/underscore.js
  - app/assets/js/underscore.strings.js


other_app:
  - <<: *application
  - app/assets/js/underscore.strings.js
  - app/assets/js/vendor/angularjs/angular.js
  - app/assets/js/vendor/angularjs/angular-sanitize.js
  - app/assets/js/vendor/angular_plugins/**/*.js
```

It only has a difference of 1 space. Check this link: http://goo.gl/mUFNud

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is the following

```
 application: &application
    - app/assets/js/vendor/jquery-2.1.1.js
    - app/assets/js/vendor/underscore.js
    - app/assets/js/underscore.strings.js


  other_app:
    - *application
    - app/assets/js/underscore.strings.js
    - app/assets/js/vendor/angularjs/angular.js
    - app/assets/js/vendor/angularjs/angular-sanitize.js
    - app/assets/js/vendor/angular_plugins/**/*.js
```

No <<: Just *application